# Reduce an array of objects based on an object array property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help from some JavaScript/NodeJS experts. I'm using the v14 of NodeJS.

I would like to create a function that takes as an **input** this kind of array (let's say that it's a list of teams):

```
[
    {
        name: 'IT',
        tags: ['Department', 'Section', 'Organizational']
    },
    {
        name: 'Male',
        tags: ['Gender', 'Organizational']
    },
    {
        name: 'Foo',
        tags: []
    }
 ]
```

... and returns as an output **a list of teams by tag name** like this:

```
// Output:
{
    Department: 'IT',
    Section: 'IT',
    Organizational: 'IT, Male',
    Gender: 'Male'
}
```

The order of object keys as well as the order of the team names don't matter. I can do this quite easily with a few lines of code, but I'm quite sure that it would be easy to do using a few of our magic `map()`, `reduce()` functions and other utilities like spreading.

Anybody can help me achieve this in an optimized way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  const organization = [
    {
        name: 'IT',
        tags: ['Department', 'Section', 'Organizational']
    },
    {
        name: 'Male',
        tags: ['Gender', 'Organizational']
    },
    {
        name: 'Foo',
        tags: []
    }
 ]


 const result = organization.reduce((acum, current) => {
   current.tags.forEach(tag => {
     if(acum[tag]) acum[tag] = `${acum[tag]}, ${current.name}`
     else acum[tag] = current.name
   })
   return acum
  },{}) 
  
  console.log(result)
```